# How to use protocol extensions with where clause

Tags: swift, where-clause, swift-protocols

```
protocol aView: class { } 

extension aView where Self: UIView { }
```

Can any one please help me to understand this code?

Comment: Side note: `aView` is a very bad name because it does not start with a capital letter and it is not a view. Use something like `MyProtocol` or `SomeFunctionalityAble`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your extension extends functionality to all types that:

- conform to `aView`

and

- are of type `UIView`